# How to make a container with fixed size regardless of the window size?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, transform

I am building a hierarchical tree with transforms where containers of color at some nodes.

I wonder why my bounding container (in red) stretches when the window size changes.

What to do to make every Container stick with the requested size? (or any alternate solution).

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    const sw = 600.0;
    const sh = sw/2;
    const scale = 0.5;
    const offset = Offset(sw/2/scale, sh/2/scale);
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Transform.translate(offset: Offset(w/2,h/2),
        child:Transform.scale(scale:scale, 
           child: Transform.translate(offset:  Offset(-offset.dx,-offset.dy),
             child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children:[
               Transform.translate(offset: Offset.zero, child: Container(width: sw, height: sh,color: Colors.red)), 
               Transform.translate(offset: Offset(10,30), child: Container(width: 400,height: 200,color:Colors.green, 
                  child: Stack(clipBehavior: Clip.none, children:[
                   Transform.translate(offset: Offset(70,10), child: 
                      Container(width: 200, height: 100, color:Colors.blue, 
               child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Pushed:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ))])))])))),
```

[UPDATED]

And a DartPad to demonstrate the issue: [The pad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=6ca8d612fa746b0589656634698f22ee&null_safety=true)

Comment: Just fixed an issue with the dart pad id that wasn't leading to the right dartpad

Answer (score 0):

change using sw and sh to w and h or assign w and h values to sw and sh.

First print the w and h value and then make modification of that value.
For example,
w = 1000, use w * 0.6

Comment: Setting w and to a fixed value does not solve anything